# how to run mutliple thread groups with different database users in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I've set of sql-files they need to execute in parallel and I've achieved it by ThreadGroups.

I've created 2 thread groups. Each TG will start each sql-file, But, they are running with same database-user.

I need to run the TG1 with user1 and TG2 with user2. Can we achieve it throw single jmx ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 (or more) [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) which will be similar except the user and password

When you write your JDBC Request give the relevant `Variable Name` from the Configuration.

> Variable Name
>   Name of the JMeter variable that the connection pool is bound to. This must agree with the 'Variable Name' field of a JDBC Connection Configuration.